# Why is there a separation between the iterator operator and Iterable interface in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am very confused about the separation between `operator fun iterator()` and the `Iterable` interface. The only function that `Iterable` requires is `operator fun iterator()`, which is already built into the language. I can't figure out why there would be any case that you would implement `operator fun iterator()` but not the `Iterable` interface as well. This begs the question: why are you able to make something iterable without implementing the corresponding interface? It seems like it would be a mistake to do so. Likewise, shouldn't `operator fun next()` and `operator fun hasNext()` always correspond to an `Iterator` type?

I tried to check if implementing `operator fun iterator()` for a type to see if it automatically implements `Iterable` behind the scenes, but that doesn't seem to be the case. The only other reason I can think of is some kind of interoperability with Java iterators.

```
class Foo(val n: Int) {
    operator fun iterator() = FooIterator(this) 
    // Shouldn't the language figure out that Foo is iterable?
}

class FooIterator(val foo: Foo): Iterator<Int> {
    var seen = false
    // Implementation goes here
}

fun <T> printAll(iter: Iterable<T>) {
    for (x in iter) {
        println("$x")
    }
}

fun main() {
    printAll(Foo(2)) // Type mismatch: Foo is not Iterable
}
```

It would make sense that any class that implements `iterator()`, `next()` and `hasNext()`, `invoke`, etc. would always implement the corresponding interface. Why was the language designed this way, where this is not always the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a general rule: defining functions with the same name/type as ones in an interface doesn't implement the interface. Why should `Iterable` and `Iterator` be exceptions? (The technical term is that subtyping in Kotlin is [nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system), not [structural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).)

> I can't figure out why there would be any case that you would implement operator fun iterator() but not the Iterable interface as well.

E.g. when `iterator` is an extension function. In [the standard library](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/iterator.html)

```
operator fun <T> Iterator<T>.iterator(): Iterator<T>
operator fun <K, V> Map<out K, V>.iterator(): Iterator<Entry<K, V>>
@JvmName("mutableIterator") operator fun <K, V> MutableMap<K, V>.iterator(): MutableIterator<MutableEntry<K, V>>
```

And `next()`/`hasNext()` (and `iterator()` too) could be defined as extension functions for [`java.util.Enumeration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) in case you are unlucky enough to work with old code using it.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that `operator fun iterator()`, `operator fun next()` and `operator fun hasNext()` are defined at the language syntax level, i.e. they are the low level requirements on objects to be used in syntax constructions (namely `for` loops).

```
class Example {
    fun someFun() {
        for (anInt in NotIterable()) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

class NotIterable  {

    // the 'iterator' returned is not actually an Iterator<> instance
    // it just an object which happen to have the right functions
    operator fun iterator() : NotIterator {
        return NotIterator()
    }
}

class NotIterator {
    operator fun hasNext(): Boolean {
        ...
    }

    operator fun next(): Int {
        ...
    }
}
```

On the other hand `Iterable` and `Iterator` are defined in the language library. They are build on top of the operators functions and add a rich and convenient API, including quite a few extension functions.